# How to store a excel file before getting download

Tags: php, yii

I am creating the excel file by using the following code:

```
ob_clean();
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

This is directly downloading but I want to store in some location so that I can use further like sending that file as the attachment. How will I achieve that?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

This helped me to achieve my problem. Thank You.

```
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  '/uploads/files/'.$fileName;
chmod($dir, 0777);
$data =  $headings . $dataCsv;
file_put_contents($dir, $data);
```

Comment: Show us the code where you create the file.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the file you just need to copy it to a location of your choice.

```
copy($filename, $wherever_you_want_to_save_the_file);
```

Comment: But How will I prevent to download the file?

Comment: Oh you dont want to download the file? Just store it?

Comment: Yes/. I just want to store the file in some location

Comment: Then dont write out those headers

Comment: You have to do something after copying the file though, right?

Comment: `file_put_contents()` is this is the solution?? I am trying this also its not working

Comment: So instead of writing the headers, send a mail